# how to Find the PROPORTION of a population for a STANDARD NORMAL between infinity and 1.25?

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, z-score

i am practicing how to find Z score and i want to know how to find Zscore for infinity. because Z score table does not have that value.

Comment: The z score for infinity is infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proportion of the area below the curve of standard normal density between 1.25 and infinity, which is the probability that the standard normal random variable, $Z>1.25$ is $P(Z>1.25) = 1-P(Z<1.25)$. This will allow you to find the result in the tables.